# What is the best/cleaner way to parse this text in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to parse the following text from an SVG.prop file:

```
parameters.styleList.0.fill=rgb (255, 0, 0)

parameters.styleList.0.key=-2.74, -2.391666666666667

parameters.styleList.0.markerSize=10,10

parameters.styleList.0.stroke=rgb (255, 0, 0)

parameters.styleList.0.strokeCapType=

parameters.styleList.0.strokeDashArray=

parameters.styleList.0.strokeJoinType=

parameters.styleList.0.strokeWidth=0.5px

parameters.styleList.0.symbol=

parameters.styleList.0.title=-2.740 - -2.392

parameters.styleList.1.fill=rgb (255, 85, 0)

parameters.styleList.1.key=-2.391666666666667, -2.0433333333333334

parameters.styleList.1.markerSize=10,10

parameters.styleList.1.stroke=rgb (255, 85, 0)

parameters.styleList.1.strokeCapType=

parameters.styleList.1.strokeDashArray=

parameters.styleList.1.strokeJoinType=

parameters.styleList.1.strokeWidth=0.5px

parameters.styleList.1.symbol=

parameters.styleList.1.title=-2.392 - -2.043
```

I need to get, for each class (3rd value in lines "parameters.styleList.**0**.key") the "fill", "key" and "title" values.
What is the best way of doing this in Python3?
Thanks

Comment: What is your current approach? Did you try anything so far? Do you have had a look at other questions such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15857818/python-svg-parser ?

Comment: @dorvak That question is not relevant, as this is not an SVG file, but apparently a properties file describing an SVG somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's straightforward to parse with regexps, using the `re` module.

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint

data = """
parameters.styleList.0.fill=rgb (255, 0, 0)
parameters.styleList.0.key=-2.74, -2.391666666666667
parameters.styleList.0.markerSize=10,10
parameters.styleList.0.stroke=rgb (255, 0, 0)
parameters.styleList.0.strokeCapType=
parameters.styleList.0.strokeDashArray=
parameters.styleList.0.strokeJoinType=
parameters.styleList.0.strokeWidth=0.5px
parameters.styleList.0.symbol=
parameters.styleList.0.title=-2.740 - -2.392
parameters.styleList.1.fill=rgb (255, 85, 0)
parameters.styleList.1.key=-2.391666666666667, -2.0433333333333334
parameters.styleList.1.markerSize=10,10
parameters.styleList.1.stroke=rgb (255, 85, 0)
parameters.styleList.1.strokeCapType=
parameters.styleList.1.strokeDashArray=
parameters.styleList.1.strokeJoinType=
parameters.styleList.1.strokeWidth=0.5px
parameters.styleList.1.symbol=
parameters.styleList.1.title=-2.392 - -2.043
"""


style_re = re.compile('^parameters\.styleList\.(?P<id>.+?)\.(?P<property>.+?)=(?P<value>.*)$', re.MULTILINE)

styles = defaultdict(dict)

for match in style_re.finditer(data):
    id, property, value = match.groups()
    styles[id][property] = value

pprint(dict(styles))
```

outputs

```
{'0': {'fill': 'rgb (255, 0, 0)',
       'key': '-2.74, -2.391666666666667',
       'markerSize': '10,10',
       'stroke': 'rgb (255, 0, 0)',
       'strokeCapType': '',
       'strokeDashArray': '',
       'strokeJoinType': '',
       'strokeWidth': '0.5px',
       'symbol': '',
       'title': '-2.740 - -2.392'},
 '1': {'fill': 'rgb (255, 85, 0)',
       'key': '-2.391666666666667, -2.0433333333333334',
       'markerSize': '10,10',
       'stroke': 'rgb (255, 85, 0)',
       'strokeCapType': '',
       'strokeDashArray': '',
       'strokeJoinType': '',
       'strokeWidth': '0.5px',
       'symbol': '',
       'title': '-2.392 - -2.043'}}
```